# Display sidebar menu elements based on user's role, with "yaminncco/vue-sidebar-menu" package

Tags: laravel, vue.js, sidebar, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

Hi I'm using Laravel Breeze with Inertia JS. I'm using **"yaminncco / vue-sidebar-menu package"** for the sidebar.

I'm asking if there is a way to display menu element depending on the user role (admin : See everything, simple user not, ....). There is nothing about this in the package doc.

So if any one has an idea Or Can suggest a better way (or package) for building sidebar when working with Laravel Breeze?

Thanks

Comment: can you pass the user role as a prop to the component and then check the role based on the prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is something you want to do in all of your pages, you can do this sharing the property via the `HandleInertiarRequests` middleware `share` method.

```php
public function share(Request $request)
{
   return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
      'user_role' => Auth::user()->role
   ]);
}
```

Now all of your pages will receive this prop at `$pages.props.user_role` on your Vue page components. Then you can do:

```html
<template>
    <sidebar-menu v-if="user_role === 'admin'" :menu="menu" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
   props: {
      user_role: String
   }
}
</script>
```

If you're using the sidebar component on a Vue component that is not a page component, for example, in a layout component, you'll have the compute the prop from the `$page.props`:

```html
<template>
    <sidebar-menu v-if="user_role === 'admin'" :menu="menu" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
   computed: {
      user_role () {
         return this.$page.props.user_role
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

If you want to select which menu items the menu should render based on the `user_role` you can compute the `menu` property:

```js
export default {
   data () {
      return {
         menuItems: [
            {
               href: '/',
               title: 'Dashboard',
               icon: 'fa fa-user'
            },
            {
               href: '/charts',
               title: 'Charts',
               icon: 'fa fa-chart-area',
               admin: true
            } 
         ]
      }
   },
   computed: {
      menu () {
         if (this.user_role === 'admin') {
            return this.menuItems // return all the items
         }

         return this.menuItems.filter((item) => {
            return !item.admin // return only items NOT marked as admin
         })
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using "yaminncco/vue-sidebar-menu" package. So when you pass the user_role as a prop to that component is there a way to handle that from inside the component in order to display only the links depending on the user role. This is the link of the package if you have any idea otherwise I know about the HandleInertiarRequests. here is the package link:  https://github.com/yaminncco/vue-sidebar-menu/tree/next

Comment: Ok... now I get it! I updated the answer to include this feature... Give it a look and see if that is what you were looking for...

Comment: I appreciate your help, Thanks a lot, It works. I want just to add a small detail to last section where you mentioned the filter method I added return also before, to make it works like this :                     return this.menuItems.filter(item => {return !item.admin })

Comment: Right... I missed that... Thanks... Glad I'm helped...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide menu items according to your user role (or according to user groups). Make sure that you get menu instance by calling a function because hidden properties must be updated each time.
Example:

```
function getMenu() {
  return [
    {
      header: 'Main Navigation'
    },
    {
      href: '/',
      title: 'Dashboard',
      hidden: !checkPermission(DashboardPage.groups),
    }
    {
      href: '/configuration',
      title: 'Configuration',
      hidden: !checkPermission(ConfigurationPage.groups),
    }
  ]
}

const menuComputed = computed(() => {
  if(loggedIn.value) {
    return getMenu();
  }
  else {
    return menuLoginOnly.value;
  }
});

...

 <sidebar-menu
   class="sidebar"
   :menu="menuComputed"/>
```